# Calculate Lat / Lon values in a Spatialite point layer

Tags: spatialite

I've a point layer in Spatialite in EPSG32632 system reference.

Then I've added two columns to calculate x, y coordinates in this way

```
ALTER TABLE points ADD COLUMN X REAL
ALTER TABLE points ADD COLUMN Y REAL
```

and calculate the coordinates in this way

```
SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');
UPDATE points SET X=ST_X("Geometry") , Y=ST_Y("Geometry")
```

Now I need to calculate the Lat, Lon values too.

I've tried this

```
ALTER TABLE points ADD COLUMN LON double;
ALTER TABLE points ADD COLUMN LAT double;
UPDATE points SET LON=ST_X(ST_Transform(geometry,4326));
UPDATE points SET LAT=ST_Y(ST_Transform(geometry,4326));
```

No errors in the execution but if I try

```
select X,Y,LON,LAT from points;
```

the result is

```
492051.358020695|4927339.50750624||
488162.133600385|4919734.42606608||
527761.520720489|4906898.57798871||
```

so, LON and LAT are empty.

Suggestions?

Comment: Hi Cesare, it's my fault (I've just updated my previous answer, sorry)... Consider LON and LAT as REAL, not double. These are the datatypes in SQLite 3: https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Hi @afalciano, I've tried also with REAL but the fields are still empty ... :-(

Comment: @afalciano Double is a valid name for a datatype in SQLite. Almost anything is because of the dynamic type system as you can read from the document that you cited. The Chapter 3.1.1. Affinity Name Examples even mentiones "double".

Comment: @user30184 Ok for the double datatype, however I can reproduce the error in SpatiaLite GUI creating a db via ogr2ogr: `ogr2ogr -f SQLite punti.sqlite points.shp`. Maybe it happens for some SpatiaLite gotchas.

Comment: What if you do `ogr2ogr -f SQLite -dsco spatialite=yes -a_srs epsg:32632 punti.sqlite points.shp`? With your command the result is a FDO style SQLite database, not a SpatiaLite db. -a_srs is not necessary if GDAL can find the source SRS. That can be tested with `ogrinfo -al -so points.shp`. If re-projection is needed then naturally -t_srs is needed, perhaps together with -s_srs.

Comment: @user30184 You're right, it works like a charm now! I've forgotten to use the datasource creation option `-dsco spatialite=yes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong in your SQL. I reproduced your case and as you can see I have lon and lat columns populated.

```
create table points (id integer, x double, y double, lon double, lat double);
select AddGeometryColumn('points','geometry',32632,'POINT');
insert into points (id,geometry) values (1,ST_GeomFromText('POINT (492051.358020695 4927339.50750624)',32632));
UPDATE points SET X=ST_X("Geometry") , Y=ST_Y("Geometry");
UPDATE points SET LON=ST_X(ST_Transform(geometry,4326));
UPDATE points SET LAT=ST_Y(ST_Transform(geometry,4326));

SELECT ROWID, "id", "x", "y", "lon", "lat", "geometry"
FROM "points";

1   1   492051.358021   4927339.507506  8.900015    44.499329   BLOB sz=60 GEOMETRY
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it works fine for me too. This means that something strange is in my data .. I'll check for this!!

Comment: I would check first that your table "points" is really registered as EPSG:32632 in geometry_columns. If SpatiaLite does  not know the source SRS it does not know how to convert coordinates into the target SRS.

Comment: You're right!! I've checked and there was "0" as srid ... Now I've changed to "32632" and all works fine!